# State Variable not getting updated using Hooks to control radio-button selection

Tags: reactjs, usehooks-ts

Problem:
Using simple togglebutton from react-bootstrap and want the selection toggle be visible at webpage. ToggleButton correctly initalises with the initial value i.e. 'b' but then never changes even though actual state variable gets updated (confirmed through console messages).

Code:

```
const SLAWidget = (props) => {
    const [action, setAction] = useState('b');
    const handleonChange=(val) => { console.log('Clicked', val); setAction(val); }
    // let controls =

    console.log('Rendering ActionValue',action)
    return (
        <Table size='sm'>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Actions:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ButtonGroup className="mb-2">
                            <ToggleButton id='inter-tbg-radio-1' type="radio" variant='outline-danger' value='a' checked={action === 'a'} onChange={(e)=>handleonChange(e.target.value)}>
                            a
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ToggleButton id='inter-tbg-radio-2' type="radio" variant='outline-danger' value='b' checked={action === 'b'} onChange={(e)=>handleonChange(e.target.value)}>
                               b
                            </ToggleButton>
                           
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    {action}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );    
}
```

Results:
When I click any of the radio-button nothing changes visibly.
[![visible component][1]][1]

Though updated values getting displayed in console as:

```
Console:
Clicked b
Rendering ActionValue b
Clicked a
Rendering ActionValue a
```

Neither visible classes changes for these buttons nor the value displayed past them changes from b to a.
What is causing this behaviour?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM97z.png

Comment: The toggle buttons are controlled by the buttongroup component.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/buttons#togglebuttongroup
So you might want to set the value (in your case `action`) to the button group instead of the checked prop in your toggle button.

Comment: It is true for TogggleButtonGroup but not for ButtonGroup, I used example given at the same page i.e. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/buttons/#checkbox--radio